# How to run docker-compose in production

Tags: docker, docker-compose, production

I have built a MEAN stack application with nginx front end.

I have 2 docker files - one for front end and one for back end
And I have a docker-compose file that pulls them together along with the database

This works great on my development machine

I then push the images to my dockerhub site

On my production ubuntu machine I pull the images that I want from my dockerhub repository

But how should I run them?

I transfer my docker-compose file to the server and try to run it:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.prod.yml up
```

but it complains that the folder structure isnt what I have on my dev machine:

```
ERROR: build path /home/demo/api either does not exist, is not accessible, or is not a valid URL.
```

I dont want to put all the code on the server and rebuild it.. surely that defeats the purpose of using dockerhub images?

I also need the docker compose file to pull in the .prod.env file for database credentials etc.

I know Im missing something here.
How do I run my images without rebuilding them from scratch?

Do I need another service for this?

Thanks in advance

docker-compose.prod.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  # Database    
  database:
    env_file:
      - .prod.env
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    environment:
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
      # Create a new database. Please note, the
      # /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js has to be executed
      # in order for the database to be created
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
    volumes:
      # Add the db-init.js file to the Mongo DB container
      - ./mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh:ro
      - /data/db
    ports:
      - '27017-27019:27017-27019'
    networks:
      - backend-net
  # Database management    
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: database
    depends_on:
      - database
    networks:
      - backend-net

  # Nodejs API
  backend:
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file:
      - .prod.env
    build:
      context: ./api
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-PROD-API
    # Note: put this container name into proxy.conf.json for local angular CLI development instead of localhost
    container_name: node-api-prod
    networks:
      - backend-net

  # Nginx and compiled angular app
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./ui
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-PROD-UI
    ports:
      - "8180:80"
    container_name: nginx-ui-prod
    networks:
      - backend-net
networks:
  backend-net:
    driver: bridge
```

DOCKERFILE-PROD-API:

```
#SERVER ========================================
FROM node:10-alpine as server

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

#RUN ls -lha

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

DOCKERFILE-PROD-UI:

```
#APP ========================================
FROM node:10-alpine as build

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install @angular/cli && npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

#RUN ls -lha

#FINAL ========================================
FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine

COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Comment: You are trying to build the containers and it is saying that you have no 'api' folder in '/home/demo' which I'm assuming is where you are running the docker-compose command from.

Comment: Yes.. but does that mean I have to copy all the files from dev onto my production server? I would like to run the containers.. not build them.

Comment: Look at the no build option here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

Comment: Many thanks .. actually in the end the solution for me was to change the image name to the full name from my dockerhub repository.. that way when I did docker-compose up on the production server it was able to use the images that were pushed (and pulled) from dockerhub and no build was required. I will post my new files below

Answer (score 0):

Using full image names including dockerhub path resolved the issue for me.

Working solution shown below:

Dockerfile-PROD-UI

```
#GET ANGULAR ========================================
FROM node:10-alpine as base
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY ui/package*.json ./
RUN npm install @angular/cli && npm install
COPY ui/. .

#BUILD ANGULAR ========================================
FROM base as build 
RUN npm run build
#RUN ls -lha

#NGINX ========================================
FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine
COPY --from=build /usr/src/app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Dockerfile-PROD-API

```
#SERVER ========================================
FROM node:10-alpine as server

WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

#RUN ls -lha

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.5'
services:
  # Database
  database:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    env_file:
      - .prod.env
    environment:
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      # MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ADMIN_PASSWORD
      # Create a new database. Please note, the
      # /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.js has to be executed
      # in order for the database to be created
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
      DB_NAME: $DB_NAME
      DB_USER: $DB_USER
      DB_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
    volumes:
      # Add the db-init.js file to the Mongo DB container
      - ./mongo-init.sh:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/mongo-init.sh:ro
      - db-data:/data/db
    ports:
      - '27017-27019:27017-27019'
    networks:
      - backend-net

  # Nodejs API
  backend:
    image: DOCKERHUBHUSER/DOCKERHUB_REPO:prod-backend
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - database
    env_file:
      - .prod.env
    build:
     context: ./api
     dockerfile: Dockerfile-PROD-API
    container_name: backend
    networks:
      - backend-net
  # Nginx and compiled angular app
  frontend:
    image: DOCKERHUBHUSER/DOCKERHUB_REPO:prod-frontend
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - backend
    build:
     context: .
     dockerfile: Dockerfile-PROD-UI
    ports:
      - "8180:80"
    container_name: frontend
    networks:
      - backend-net
networks:
  backend-net:
    driver: bridge
volumes:
  db-data:
    name: db-data
    external: true
```